# Changing values in a namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have a set of C++ files that I am using for physical simulations. For these simulations, I wrote a namespace with necessary constants that are used in all of the .cpp files. Now I want to run a different set of simulations. Except for the namespace, the code is completely portable in that regard, but I need to change the constants in the namespace.

Can a namespace have a set function to set static constants or something along these lines? If not, any other ideas on how to approach this? I would like an input flag for the final executable that sets which simulation to run, and then the correct constants are decided for all .cpp files internally.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is your problem? If the "constants" are `const` then there's no way to change them. If they are not `const`, just write a function which sets them.

Comment: How are the constants declared? Offhand I can't think of a good way of switching between two sets at runtime. One approach might be to set the constants in a data file, and specify that file as a runtime parameter. Whatever you do, make it "future-proof" by designing a mechanism that allows a third set (unless the simulations, by their nature, can only have two sets).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mentioned static, so I'm assuming you have these constants included in multiple files as `static const double a = ...`.

The easiest and simplest way I can think of that doesn't involve you touching other parts of your code is changing the constants to not be `static const` but rather to `extern` and then you can have another source file that contains them and exposes a function to set them up.

Example: http://ideone.com/t0gUKO

If you want to go a more c++esque way, you can define an interface class that provides functions to access the constant values, and then you implement this class for each of the different test cases you run.